# REST API OAuth Authorization and Authentication

Tags: authentication-authorization, 9

I am very much confused about the way OAuth authorization and authentication works in Drupal 8/9.
Let me put my points first, please correct me if I am wrong.

- Authorization is when an entity proves a right to access.
- Authentication is when an entity proves an identity.

I have done the following to implement a REST API which is intended to be consumed by mobile applications (Android and iOS).

- Installed and/or enabled modules: Simple OAuth, REST UI, RESTful Web Services, Serialization.
- Created a new role for specifying the scope of simple OAuth consumer, and set required permissions.
- Created a consumer by adding RSA key pair, password and scope.
- Succeeded in getting the response from `/oauth/token` by submitting a request body containing `grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `username` and `password`.

The question is, why we need to send the `username` and `password`, for getting the `access_token`, since we are only trying to **Authorize the API Request and NOT Authenticate the User**?

Also, what should I do to **Authorize the API request with OAuth but need to access contents without authentication**? Should I create a dummy user and always send this user credentials to get access_token?

It would be very helpful if someone can explain the concept and how should one proceed.

Reference I followed: https://dev.acquia.com/blog/decoupled-drupal-authentication-oauth-20

Comment: Why not add `8` tag. Since this question also applies to Drupal 8. Also additionally, it will reach those who watch tags for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got the solution. It was my mistake, that I was trying to use OAuth2 3-legged authorization, but I am actually need OAuth 2-legged authorization.

More Details on oAuth Flow and Grant Types: [oAuth Grant Types](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/which-grant/)